# Squid Http proxy doesn't work in git clone

Tags: proxy, squid, git, http-proxy

I've installed the [Squid through Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/sameersbn/squid/) and tested with curl and browser, it works fine!

And then I'm going to set the Http proxy to git, the below is my command:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://myserverip:3128
```

And then, here is the result of the above command in the git config.

```
$ cat ~/.gitconfig
[http]
    proxy = http://squid.veronalabs.com:3128
    sslVerify = false
```

But the git clone doesn't work!

```
$ git clone git@gitlab.com:repo/project.git
Cloning into 'panel'...
ssh: connect to host gitlab.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

And anyway, I've added this proxy for outgoing connections:

```
$ export http_proxy=http://myserverip:3128
$ export https_proxy=http://myserverip:3128
```

I really appreciate any helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using http.proxy but trying to clone the repository with SSH. you should use the https GitLab link.

Comment: Hum, It's reasonable! here is the result of Http method. `fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/repo/project.git/': Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT`

Comment: code 403 is forbidden, so maybe you should talk to your squid administrator ;-)

Comment: I figured out, used another image, worked fine. https://hub.docker.com/r/babim/squid/